# Galois cohomology class of a reductive group not coming from a torus

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a (connected) reductive group over a perfect field $k$, and let $\xi\in H^1(k,G)$ be a cohomology class.
By a theorem of Steinberg (Serre, Galois cohomology, Appendix 1 to Chapter III, Theorem 11.1),
*if $G$ is quasi-split,* then there exists a $k$-torus $i\colon T\hookrightarrow G$ such that
$$\xi\in i_* \big(H^1(k,T)\big).$$

> **Question.** What is an example of $k$, a non-quasi-split reductive $k$-group $G$, and  $\xi\in H^1(k,G)$, such that $\xi$ *does not come* from a $k$-torus?

**Remark.** Such $k$ cannot be $\Bbb R$, a $p$-adic field or a number field.
Indeed, let $G$ be a reductive $k$-group, *not necessarily quasi-split*.
If $k$ is $\Bbb R$ or a $p$-adic field, then there exists a $k$-torus  $i\colon T\hookrightarrow G$
such that the map
$$i_*\colon H^1(k,T)\to H^1(k,G) $$
is surjective.
If $k$ is a number field, then for any finite set $\Xi=\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\}\subset H^1(k,G)$ there exists a $k$-torus
$i\colon T\hookrightarrow G$ such that $\Xi\subset i_*\big( H^1(k,T)\big)$.
For the last assertion, see M. Borovoi, Abelian Galois cohomology of reductive groups, Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 132 (1998), no. 626,
Theorem 5.10.

Comment: The fact about surjectivity of $H^1(\mathbb R, T) \to H^1(\mathbb R, G)$ for some $T$ doesn't require that $G$ have a compact-mod-centre $T$?

Comment: @LSpice: No, it does not. Let $T_0\subset G$ be a maximal compact torus. Then the natural map $$H^1({\Bbb R}, T_0)\to H^1({\Bbb R}, G)$$ is surjective. See [my preprint (to appear in Commun. Math.)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5913.pdf), Lemma 3(b) and Theorem 9.

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424141/galois-cohomology-class-of-a-reductive-group-not-coming-from-a-torus#comment1098805_424141)!  So I guess it *does* require a compact torus, just not a compact-mod-centre *maximal* torus (which I had implicitly assumed).

Comment: Any connected reductive $\Bbb R$-group contains a compact torus, namely, the trivial torus $\{1\}$. If $G$ is a split $\Bbb R$-torus, then $\{1\}$ is a maximal compact torus.

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424141/galois-cohomology-class-of-a-reductive-group-not-coming-from-a-torus#comment1099012_424141); I did not mean to doubt the existence of a maximal compact torus (as you say it is obvious), only to point out my own error in [saying](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424141/galois-cohomology-class-of-a-reductive-group-not-coming-from-a-torus#comment1098804_424141) "compact-mod-centre torus" when I meant "compact-mod-centre maximal torus".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\la}{\langle}\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}$The  following example is due to Vladimir Chernousov (private communication).

Let $K={\Bbb Q}(x,y,x',y')$, where $x,y,x',y'$ are variables.
Consider the quadratic forms over $K$
$$ f= \la x,y,-xy\ra\qquad\text{and}\qquad f'=\la x',y',-x'y'\ra.$$
Here $ \la x,y,-xy\ra$ denotes the quadratic form $$f(t_1,t_2,t_3)=xt_1^2+yt_2^2-xyt_3^2.$$

> **Lemma 1.** The quadratic form  over $K$
> $$ f-f'=\la x,y,-xy, -x',-y', x'y'\ra$$
> is anisotropic (does not represent 0 nontrivially).

*Proof.* The quadratic form $f-f'$ is monomial and multiplicity free
in the sense of Section 4 of Vladimir Chernousov and Jean-Pierre Serre,
*Lower bounds for essential dimensions via orthogonal representations,*
J. Algebra 305 (2006), no. 2, 1055–1070.
By their Proposition 5 on page 1061, the quadratic form $f-f'$ is anisotropic,
as required.

Consider the quaternion $K$-algebras
$$ D=(x,y)\qquad  \text{and} \qquad D'=(x',y').$$
Here $(x,y)$ denotes the 4-dimensional associative $K$-algebra with generators $i,j$ and relations
$$i^2=x,  \quad j^2=y,\quad    ij=-ji.$$
The reduced norm form for $D$ is isomorphic  to  $\ \la 1\ra-f=\la 1,-x,-y,xy\ra$.

> **Lemma 2.** The algebraic $K$-groups $G={\rm PGL}(1,D)$ and $G'={\rm PGL}(1,D')$ have no isomorphic maximal tori.

*Proof.*
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $G$ and $G'$ have isomorphic maximal tori.
Then $D$ and $D'$ have isomorphic maximal subfields, say, $L\subset D$ and $L'\subset D'$.
Write $L=K(\sqrt{a})\subset D$ for $a\in K$.
This implies that there exists a pure quaternion $t_1 i+t_2 j+t_3ij$ such that
$$xt_1^2+yt_2^2-xyt
_3^2=a.$$
Thus the quadratic form $f$ represents $a$.
Similarly, from $L'=K(\sqrt{a})\subset D'$ (with the same $a$) we obtain that $f'$ represents $a$.
Therefore, the quadratic form $f-f'$ represents 0 nontrivially, which contradicts Lemma 1.

> **Theorem.** For $G$ and $G'$ as above, let $c\in Z^1(K,G)$ is a 1-cocycle such that  $_c G\simeq G'$.
> Then the cohomology class $[c]\in H^1(K,G)$ does not come from a maximal torus of $G$.

*Proof.*
Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exists a maximal torus
$$ j\colon T\hookrightarrow G\quad\text{such that }\quad [c]\in j_* H^1(K,T).$$
Then there exists an embedding
$$j'\colon T\hookrightarrow {}_c G\simeq G'.$$
Thus $G$ and $G'$ have isomorphic maximal tori, which contradicts Lemma 2.

Comment: I typed this answer from Chernousov's email messages and handwritten notes. The responsibility for  the possible mistakes is mine.